# How to use ajax to re-render selectManyCheckbox from selectOneRadio

Tags: jsf, trinidad

I'm trying to use a `selectOneRadio` to redraw some of my components (namely enabling/disabling them). I've tried just using the id of my `selectManyCheckbox`; didn't work. I also tried putting the `selectManyCheckbox` inside of a `h:panelGroup`; also didn't work. I'm pretty sure my tags are properly created, since I don't know how else it could work.

This is what I have so far:

```
    <tr:selectOneRadio id="useFilterChoices" value="#{randomCardBean.useFilters}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="All Cards" itemValue="allCards"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Filter By Category" itemValue="someCards"/>
        <f:ajax event="click" render="categoryChoicesBox"/>
    </tr:selectOneRadio>

    <tr:selectManyCheckbox id="categoryChoicesBox" disabled="#{randomCardBean.filterDisabled}" value="#{randomCardBean.selectedFilters}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{randomCardBean.filterChoices}"/>
    </tr:selectManyCheckbox>
```

I'm using selectOneRadio because I want to be able to extend the filter options eventually. Any help on this would be MUCH appreciated!

Comment: sry for the elementaries - are all the tags in question in a form?

Comment: Yes, they are all in a `tr:subform`. I eventually fixed it by using partial submits and figuring out the differences between the value for the `tr:selectItems` and the value in `tr:selectOneRadio`, but we ended up dropping the project.

Comment: Are you using Trinidad 1.2 or 2.0?